# CTE understanding

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a view that gets a flattened view of a project sprint. That's a day by day breakdown, future and past, for the sprint duration.

It's a rather large joining view. I am trying to use that view to get some details for a screen that is running very slowly. It's slow, because for each person in the sprint, it was calling the view (using EF and Linq), and the filtering, and then doing some sums... a few times per person.

I am trying to make a stored procedure that uses a CTE to get the view data, and then use that in a smaller join. And it's much quicker, but I am battling with a column.

Here is the CTE and it's use:

```
DECLARE @SprintId INT
SET @SprintId = 1006

;WITH Detail_CTE (PersonId, AssignedHours, AssignedProductiveHours, DateValue, CanBurnDown, OnHoliday )
AS
    (
        SELECT PersonId, AssignedHours, AssignedProductiveHours, DateValue, CanBurnDown, OnHoliday FROM vwSprintDailyBreakdown
        WHERE SprintId = @SprintId
        AND OnHoliday = 0
    ),
Detail_CTE_rem (PersonId, AssignedHours, AssignedProductiveHours, DateValue, CanBurnDown, OnHoliday )
AS
    (
        SELECT PersonId, AssignedHours, AssignedProductiveHours, DateValue, CanBurnDown, OnHoliday FROM vwSprintDailyBreakdown
        WHERE SprintId = @SprintId
        AND OnHoliday = 0
        AND DateValue >= GETUTCDATE()
    )

SELECT 
    psp.Id, 
    p.Firstname + ' '+ p.Surname, 
    rt.Description, 
    psp.JoinSprintDate, 
    psp.LeaveSprintDate,
    psp.AssignedProductiveHours,
    psp.AssignedHours,
    SUM(cteTotal.AssignedProductiveHours) AS ProdHrs


FROM project_sprint_person psp
INNER JOIN project_person pp
ON pp.Id = psp.ProjectPersonId
AND pp.deleted IS NULL
INNER JOIN person p
ON p.Id = pp.PersonId
AND p.Deleted IS NULL
LEFT JOIN resource_type rt
ON rt.Id = psp.ResourceTypeId

LEFT JOIN Detail_CTE cteTotal
ON cteTotal.PersonId = p.Id
AND cteTotal.CanBurnDown = 1

--LEFT JOIN Detail_CTE_rem cteRemain
--ON cteRemain.PersonId = p.Id
--AND cteRemain.CanBurnDown = 1


WHERE psp.ProjectSprintId = @SprintId

GROUP BY    psp.Id, 
    p.Firstname,
    p.Surname, 
    rt.Description, 
    psp.JoinSprintDate, 
    psp.LeaveSprintDate,
    psp.AssignedProductiveHours,
    psp.AssignedHours,
    rt.Weight

ORDER BY rt.Weight
```

In that form, it's working. The summed column is 100% fine.

However, I need to include "Remaining Productive Hours". For this, I want to use the same CTE data, but only get rows where 'DateValue' >= Todays date.

I tried to create a 2nd CTE to do this, as you can see, but as soon as I join to that CTE, my existing summed column value becomes incorrect.

I don't think I need the 2nd CTE... and can rather join to the same CTE in the query, aliassing it as something new. However, again, when I try that, the summed value of the existing CTE goes wrong.

How can I use one CTE (Detail_CTE) and use it for two different scenarios. One, where I get a sum of a column, and then again, getting the sum of a column, with a data  constriction.

Comment: Joining to the same cte with a different alias seems like the correct approach.  However, you have a lot going on with this query.  You might want to start a new one and build it up slowly.  In other words take baby steps.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want a conditional `SUM()`, which doesn't require an extra `JOIN` to the cte:

```
SELECT 
    psp.Id, 
    p.Firstname + ' '+ p.Surname, 
    rt.Description, 
    psp.JoinSprintDate, 
    psp.LeaveSprintDate,
    psp.AssignedProductiveHours,
    psp.AssignedHours,
    SUM(cteTotal.AssignedProductiveHours) AS ProdHrs
    SUM(CASE WHEN DateValue >= GetUTCDate() THEN cteTotal.AssignedProductiveHours
             ELSE 0
        END) AS RemainingProductiveHours
```